# How to get process pid in gjs?

Tags: gjs

What I really want to do is call `getpid()`, but there doesn't seem to be any sane way to do that in gjs. The best I've been able to come up with is:

`// There's got to be a better way to get our pid in gjs?
let credentials = new Gio.Credentials();
let pid = credentials.get_unix_pid();`

And that works, but it's horrible. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no other way than that.

Ideas for future versions of GJS include a `process` object compatible with the one in Node.